# First ImageView dissapeard after the second ImageView gets added to the RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, layoutparams

After adding a second `ImageView` to the `RelativeLayout`, the first and the second `ImageView` do not show. How can I fix it?

```
val hideImage = ImageView(ctx)
hideImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.hiding_box)
hideImage.id = hiderImageIds[0]
params.leftMargin = 0
params.topMargin = 0
hiderLayout.addView(hideImage, params)

val hideImage2 = ImageView(ctx)
hideImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.hiding_box)
hideImage2.id = hiderImageIds[1]
params.leftMargin = hiderImageWidth
params.topMargin = 0
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, hiderImageIds[0])
hiderLayout.addView(hideImage2, params)
```

Comment: You use the same `params` object for both the image views. So, I suspect, changing it for the 2nd image would change it for the 1st one.

Comment: Yeah! You are right. It worka now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `params` object for both the `ImageView`s. So, I suspect, changing it for the 2nd image would change it for the 1st one. Use different `LayoutParams`.